# Google Geo Code API returning not more than 10 suggestions for the inputs

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-api, street-address

I am doing a proof of concept to accept address as input and provide suggestions to user using google geo-code service.

I have written .Net Code to access google API. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=123+main+srt&components=country:US

when i access above URL only 10 results are returned.

Search terms/addresses i used to search are "123 main srt" and "123"

Comment: probably it is paged? I don´t know just an idea. The youtube api is paged and there you have to run through each page

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Generally, only one entry in the "results" array is returned for
>   address lookups,though the geocoder may return several results when
>   address queries are ambiguous.

So a sucessfull request will have at least 1 result, may have more, but must not have more results than 1(or 10).

Comment: How could you conclude that 1(or 10), please provide link for more understanding. For exact match input i am able to see one result element in response, for any ambiguous inputs i am able to see only 10 results elements in the response